# Protractor Won't Select From Drop-Down in IE10

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, testing, protractor

For tests run on firefox and chrome, I often use a command similar to the following to select a particular option from a select2 drop-down menu:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('.select2-result-label', 'A')).click();
```

In firefox, you can see that it selects the item from the list.
In IE, I can see the list drop down, and then it's like the cursor just flies up and down the list for a moment, but never seems to light on the right item and never selects anything.

Has anyone else seen different behavior with menus in IE and firefox?

Answer (score 0):

With IE it always comes to "special" handling.

You can try *scrolling into view* of the element before clicking:

```
var selection = element(by.cssContainingText('.select2-result-label', 'A'));
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", selection.getWebElement());
selection.click();
```

Alternatively, perform the click via `executeScript()`:

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", selection.getWebElement());
```